# My first App with App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

This is my first time using the Google App maker!

What do I need to access the editor and its features and tools?

I just submitted a form, how long it takes to give me access ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be eligible for EAP (running G Suite Business)
2. Apply for Early Adopters Program ( https://gsuite.google.com/campaigns/index__appmakereap.html) on behalf of domain administrator

Normally it take 1-3 weeks to get whitelisted

3. Open editor at https://appmaker.google.com/
4. Enjoy!